# I want to be able to get the contents of all `<b></b>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to get the contents of all `<b></b>` tags using jQuery or javascript, how can I achieve this?

For example, if I had **hello i am here**, I want to be able to get the text "hello i am here" as a string.

Answer (score 2):

To select all `<b>` elements and iterate over them:

```
$('b').each(function(){
   console.log( $(this).text() ); // hello i am here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can map them to an array:

```
var values = $("b").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$('b').text();
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6zyFU/)**

Depending of what you want to do after you will get more exact answers...

If you have many `<b>` elements and want them in a array you can use:

```
var arr = [];
$('b').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Yes it works well. But my all content in a div then how i can fetch

Comment: @user2886533, what you mean by id?

Comment: I means all my content in a div have a id.Then how i use $('b').text();

Comment: @user2886533, use this: `$('#divID b').text();` using the ID selector (#) and then the id name

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for jQuery and native javascript, I will provide a native example, although there is nothing wrong with the suggested jQuery examples.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('b');

for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    console.log(elements[i].innerText);
}
```